# Unable to parse bindings knockout error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I am working with knockout and have run in to a problem I dont know how to fix. I retrieve a json object back from an asp.net mvc controller. I pass it to the following function:

```
load = function (data) {
        var myViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self);

            self.hasItems = ko.computed(function () {
                return self.NumberOfItems > 0;
            }, self);

        };
        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, window.document.getElementById("my-container"));
    }
```

I am adding custom behaviour to my model object based upon what is returned in the json, in particular the NumberOfItems property of the json. My markup is:

```
 <div class="content" style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: hasItems === false">
    <span class="empty">My Items</span>
</div>
```

But I keep getting this error:

Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: hasItems is not defined;
Bindings value: visible: hasItems === false

I have no idea why - I am a newbie to this so really appreciate any help?

Answer (score 2):

applyBindings expects an object.  Try

```
ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel(), window.document.getElementById("my-container"));
```

Also, when you want to get the value of an observable, you'll need to use parentheses.

```
return self.NumberOfItems() > 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36xtR/

Answer (score 0):

Apart of ckal answer you probably also want to use ko.mappings this way:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
```

Comment: Thanks - whats the difference?

Comment: Second parameter is a custom mapping, if you want to specify update target you need to pass it as a third parameter - please take a look here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html in a section "Specifying the update target"

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing 'unable to parse bindings' means that knockout can't find what you are trying to bind (hasItems).

I think this is because you are only creating the viewModel when the load function is called, but at the time the bindings are being parsed the viewModel doesn't exist, so it complains.

I would try setting up your viewModel more like this:

```
var myViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.load = function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self);
        }

        self.hasItems = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.NumberOfItems > 0;
        }, self);

    };
ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel(), window.document.getElementById("my-container"));
```

You can then call the load function in the viewModel in place of where you are calling your current load function.

Comment: Do I need to create a new instance of myViewModel when passing to applyBindings eg. new myViewModel()?

Comment: Yes you do, please check ckal answer.